# How to retrieve image from database using servlet in database table format

Tags: servlets

Here is the code snippet

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            String ci= request.getParameter("CheckIn");
            String co=request.getParameter("CheckOut");
            PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
            String sql="SELECT id,image FROM `availability` WHERE check_in > '"+ci+"' or check_out < '"+co+"'";
            try {
            Statement st=conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
           response.setContentType("text/html");  
            PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
            out.print("<table  border=1>");  
            out.print("<caption>Result:</caption>");  
            while(rs.next())
            {
                int id=rs.getInt("id");
                Blob b=rs.getBlob("image");
                byte barr[]=rs.getBytes("image");
                response.setContentType("image/gif");
                ServletOutputStream os=response.getOutputStream();
                os.write(barr);
                out.print("<tr><td>"+id+"</td></tr>");
            }

    }
}
```

I want to print image on web browser that it print the image but ,I want it in the format of database Table so that I can Print the value like `Id,Name,CheckIn,CheckOut` along with image

the image in Database Table format that is

```
Id        Image
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new servlet that will servce the image.
from image do like this

```
<img src='servletpath?somparameter'>
```

and in servlet get blob form database and write to the output stream of response.

Comment: I am not getting ,what actually I have to do ?can you suggest me Please/or The code which I have written ,Can you Do The modification